# how to refresh/reload dhtmlx grid

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, visual-studio-2010, dhtmlx

I am using dhtmlx grid.I have two grids named grid1,grid2.
I have loaded the two grids using json object.

If i select one record in the grid1 and click on the button that record has to load in the second record.I am able to load that selected record in the second grid using `document.location.reload(true);`with this, the total page is refreshing.but i want to refresh grid2 only.

I want to refresh grid2 only after click on the button.how can i refresh/reload grid2.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Ajax` to load and replace the second grid. Let's say the second grid has an id of `second-grid`, something like

```
@Ajax.ActionLink("Load Second Grid", "ActionName", new AjaxOptions
{
    UpdateTargetId = "second-grid",
    InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,
    HttpMethod = "GET"
})
```

will replace what's inside `second-grid` with the result from `ActionName` when `Load Second Grid` is clicked.

Answer (score 0):

You can use onRowSelect handler to catch moment when row clicked in master grid. 
And you can use grid.parse API to load new data in second grid.

```
<script>
grid1.attachEvent("onRowSelect", function(id){
    grid2.parse(some_data, "json")
})
</script>
```